# Async not working while sending image to server?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I need to send image to service, pre-execute method working where as do in background not working. Code is below for same:

```
    private class SendImageAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        private Context context;
        private String serverUrl;
        private String path;

        public SendImageAsync(Context context, String serverUrl,
                 String path) {
            this.context = context;
            this.serverUrl = serverUrl;
            this.path = path;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            LogWrite.i(TAG, "onPreExecute method enters!!");

            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            LogWrite.i(TAG, "doInBackground method enters!!");
            byte[] imageBytes = getFileBytes(path);
            ImageToSend sendImage = new ImageToSend();
            boolean responseStatus = sendImage.send(context, serverUrl,
                    imageBytes );
            String responseString = responseStatus ? "Success!" : "Fail!";
            LogWrite.e(TAG, "Response " + responseString);
            return "";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            LogWrite.i(TAG, "onPostExecute method enters!!");
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
    }
```

Help me on same, why it is not working?

Update code:
I had created an interface, that will notify on image click and provide me path of file:

```
@Override
public void onImageCapture(File file) {
    if (file != null) {
        LogWrite.d(TAG, "File Path ::: " + file.getAbsolutePath());
        if (isFromCommand) {
            LogWrite.d(TAG, "Is from command : "+ isFromCommand);
            try {
                SendImageAsync async = new SendImageAsync (activity,
                        serverUrl, file.getAbsolutePath());
                async.execute("");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LogWrite.e(TAG, "SendImageAsync Exception : " + e.toString());
            }

        }
        Bitmap myBitmap = showBitmapFromFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
        myBitmap = RotateBitmap(myBitmap, 90);

        Drawable ob = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), myBitmap);
        saveImageView.setBackgroundDrawable(ob);
    } 
    // saveImageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
}
```

Comment: Please explain, completely and precisely, what "not working" means.

Comment: pre execute method log is showing where as do in background logs are not showing

Comment: why you are declaring asynctask like that when you are not using any of parameter

Comment: better define its as `AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>`

Comment: I do this to check why async is not working, but haven't found any issue..

Comment: Copy-pasted code ? The above looks like it...

Comment: Anything else in the logcat?

Comment: Are you using an Executor? Please post how you start the AsyncTask.

Comment: yes I copied it from my code, actually I need to send image from file explorer to server, and http request can be made in background so I used async

Comment: I had update the above code, hope it will be more clear now..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but you probably want to send a request and not a response...

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, I was using this AsyncTask on another AsyncTask, So its not working, even it was not giving any exception.

Comment: So, try put this task inside onPostExecute of another task.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the basic sample code you can refer, hope this help

```
/**
 * Async task to post file to remote web api
 */
public class PostFileToWebAPI extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Object> {    

   ...

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(String... params) {
        String filePath = params[1];
        try {                               
            return postFile(mAPI_URL, filePath);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return e.getMessage();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
        super.onPostExecute(o);            
    }      
}


private String postFile(String apiUrl, String filePath) throws Exception {
    // init httpClient, httpPost...
    ...

    MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
    builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
    File file = new File(filePath);
    FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(file);
    final long totalSize = fileBody.getContentLength();
    builder.addPart("file", fileBody);        
    httpEntity = builder.build();      
    httpPost.setEntity(httpEntity);
    httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    statusCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

    if ((statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) && (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)) {
        return httpResponse.getStatusLine().toString();
    } else {
        return getStringContent(httpResponse);
    }
}
```